# Get Mp3 total duration in seconds (or millisecond) using Media Foundation

Tags: windows, visual-c++, windows-phone-8, media

I'm developing  an Universal app for windows 8.1 and wp 8.1

and I write a little c++ source for decoding mp3 file, Now I'd like to find a way to get total time length before I've decoded the file using media foundation api.

Thanks

Comment: I know how to do this with the old Windows Media Format SDK (which also decodes MP3). But here's one issue to be aware of.  MP3 files don't have a "file header" per se. They are made up of individual MP3 frames between 500-1500 bytes each. Most MP3 files are encoded with the same bit rate throughout their encoding. As such, if you can decode the first MP3 header and get its block size, sample rate, and sample count, you can interpolate the number of frames in the entire file. ...

Comment: ... However, VBR (variable bitrate) MP3 files will have different frame blocks each with a different header indicating a different bitrate encoding.  As such, the only *accurate* way to get the duration of a VBR mp3 file is to scan through every frame block and get compute its duration.  Most SDKs won't do this - instead, will just return an estimate based on the first frame and the size of the entire file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MS Media Foundation can give you attributes of MP3 files, including duration.  There's a [sample app on Github](https://github.com/avranju/AudioPlayerWithCustomStream), and the relevant code is excerpted here.  This is not my code, and it won't work out-of-the-box with the asynchronous interface given by `StorageFile`, but the job of fitting square pegs into round holes is pretty straight-forward.

Note that `Duration` here is in 100-nanosecond ticks, per the [MF_PD_DURATION documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms702060(v=vs.85).aspx).

```
#include <collection.h>
#include <ppltasks.h>
#include <mfidl.h>
#include <mfapi.h>
#include <mfreadwrite.h>
#include <wrl.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "mf.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "mfplat.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "mfuuid.lib")

using namespace Platform;
using namespace Windows::Storage::Streams;
using namespace Microsoft::WRL;

// Only throw in exception based code (C++/CX), never throw in HRESULT error code based code.
#define THROW_IF_FAILED(hr)     { if (FAILED(hr)) throw Platform::Exception::CreateException(hr); }
#pragma comment(lib, "mfreadwrite.lib")

namespace MFUtils
{
    // This WinRT object provides JavaScript or C# code access to the information in the stream
    // that it needs to construct the AudioEncodingProperties needed to construct the AudioStreamDescriptor
    // needed to create a MediaStreamSource. Here is how to create it
    // var helper = new MFUtils.MFAttributesHelper(self.memoryStream, data.mimeType);

    public ref class MFAttributesHelper sealed
    {
    public:
        property UINT64 Duration;
        property UINT32 BitRate;
        property UINT32 SampleRate;
        property UINT32 ChannelCount;

        // The synchronous design only works with in memory streams.
        MFAttributesHelper(InMemoryRandomAccessStream^ stream, String^ mimeType)
        {
            THROW_IF_FAILED(MFStartup(MF_VERSION));
            // create an IMFByteStream from "stream"
            ComPtr<IMFByteStream> byteStream;
            THROW_IF_FAILED(MFCreateMFByteStreamOnStreamEx(reinterpret_cast<IUnknown*>(stream), &byteStream));

            // assign mime type to the attributes on this byte stream
            ComPtr<IMFAttributes> attributes;
            THROW_IF_FAILED(byteStream.As(&attributes));
            THROW_IF_FAILED(attributes->SetString(MF_BYTESTREAM_CONTENT_TYPE, mimeType->Data()));

            // create a source reader from the byte stream
            ComPtr<IMFSourceReader> sourceReader;
            THROW_IF_FAILED(MFCreateSourceReaderFromByteStream(byteStream.Get(), nullptr, &sourceReader));

            // get current media type
            ComPtr<IMFMediaType> mediaType;
            THROW_IF_FAILED(sourceReader->GetCurrentMediaType(MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_AUDIO_STREAM, &mediaType));

            // get all the data we're looking for
            PROPVARIANT prop;
            THROW_IF_FAILED(sourceReader->GetPresentationAttribute(MF_SOURCE_READER_MEDIASOURCE, MF_PD_DURATION, &prop));
            Duration = prop.uhVal.QuadPart;

            UINT32 data;
            THROW_IF_FAILED(sourceReader->GetPresentationAttribute(MF_SOURCE_READER_MEDIASOURCE, MF_PD_AUDIO_ENCODING_BITRATE, &prop));
            BitRate = prop.ulVal;

            THROW_IF_FAILED(mediaType->GetUINT32(MF_MT_AUDIO_SAMPLES_PER_SECOND, &data));
            SampleRate = data;

            THROW_IF_FAILED(mediaType->GetUINT32(MF_MT_AUDIO_NUM_CHANNELS, &data));
            ChannelCount = data;
        }

    private:
        ~MFAttributesHelper()
        {
            MFShutdown();
        }
    };
}
```